# Filtering - use drop downs with set ranges, or text boxes for arbitrary values

Tags: forms, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

If you are searching something, and want to filter the results, would you rather have text boxes to get exact ranges you want, or a drop down set ranges, that are quick and easy to select.

[image: drop downs]

[image: text boxes]

So the drop downs might have price, under $100, under $200, under $500, under $1000, etc, where as for the text boxes you could have prices between e.g. $33 and $76. More specific, but really people would only want a maximum price anyway most likely.

What is better?

Comment: What's the product domain, and have you had the opportunity to speak with users? What have you seen other successful competitors doing?
What is the characters field referring to?

Comment: What makes you say that people would only want a filter for maximum price? I use minimum price filters regularly (kijiji, amazon, ebay, etc.).

Comment: Competitors do both, max price in this scenario would very likely be enough

Answer (score 2):

**Allow user control.** This is an important [usability heuristic](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/). By forcing users to filter only 'up to' a certain amount, you are reducing the ability of users to filter their results the way they want to.

Amazon has a solution that affords selecting in a range or filtering by min/max:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you might be right, using a drop down for min and max, which is still easier than having to type in numbers. Dont you think?

Comment: Unless the numbers are in a very small range, you won't be able to use a dropdown for min and max (imagine that prices range from $1 to $1000, you'd need a 1000 item dropdown). If people want finer-grained control than the labels afford, they'll just type in numbers. You could always create a prototype and test it with some of your users, but I'm guessing if Amazon does it, it's been tested a few times. Note: I don't know for a fact that Amazon has tested this part of the interface, but it's a reasonable assumption that millions of people have used it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your assumption:

> people would only want a maximum price anyway most likely

If you do believe this is the case for your users, you may want to **ease** their choice by providing only a max range to set. So the following example is a good fit **based on your assumption**.

[image]

The point is, you should make sure the assumption is correct.

Comment: Yes, I could use a slider too, that is something to consider.